# How to avoid needing to use regex recursively to remove words at the end of a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, recursion

I want to remove terms which appear at the end of a string. For example, `LTD`, `CORP`, `LLC`, `INC`. *[in total there are about 50 or so different terms i want to remove from the end of the strings].*

My problem comes with how to remove sequences of these terms, for example with the string "COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD". In this instance i want to remove both `CORP` and `LTD` [i.e. once `LTD` has been removed, the term now ends in `CORP`, which i also want gone].

At the moment, I do this recursively, running the regex over and over again until it no longer makes a change.

```
import re

def re_run_match(match_term, replace_with, string):
    new_string_temp = re.subn(match_term, replace_with, string)
    if new_string_temp[1] == 0:
        return(new_string_temp[0])
    else:
        return(re_run_match(match_term, replace_with, new_string_temp[0]))

long_match_set = r" LTD$| CORP$| LLC$| INC$"
company_name = "COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD"
clean_company_name = re_run_match(long_match_set, "", company_name)
```

Is there a simpler way of doing than this without the recursion needed? At the moment each string tends to need to go through the regex command about 2-3 times before there are no further adjustments required, hence making the code 2 or 3 times slower than if there was a way of doing in a single operation.

Note: I do not want to remove terms which are not at the end of the string, hence why i am not just using a match term such as `r"\bLTD\b|\bCORP\b|\bLLc\b|b\INC\b"`.

Comment: Try [`(?: (?:LTD|CORP|LLC|INC))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dG8iN9/1) regex.

Comment: @stribizhev - thanks, think this works perfect - just running over data now :-)

Comment: Great, I finally lulled my son to sleep, and posted the answer :)

Comment: Thats unnecessary "(?: (?:LTD|CORP|LLC|INC))+$" is no different then " (LTD|CORP|LLC|INC)$" since you dont care about `groups()` youre just replacing it. Youre making it more complicated 'just-cause'

Comment: Here is your proof: http://rubular.com/r/qvT7EwWy3L vs http://rubular.com/r/nxanoz8qjU -- the more things you add, the more things you need to debug or read again in 3 weeks when you need to modify the code.

Comment: Do this: re.compile('( (LTD|CORP|LLC|INC))+$', re.IGNORECASE).sub('', 'COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD') you dont need to add ':?' to it, SINCE youre not using groups. (which was my point all along)

Comment: @JavierBuzzi: when you use capture groups `(...)` instead of non-capturing groups `(?:...)` you store substrings and use memory for nothing.

Comment: That makes no sense. not on a sub. Its hard to test the the memory consumption, but here are some numbers of speed. Speed has been posted on my answer.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi: obviously, with a wrong pattern, it's slower.

Comment: Whats your test case? I just added a test case that it wont match and its 2.61us vs 3.1us against `:?` -- i dont see what youre talking about

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: you were right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it with grouping and a `+` quantifier:

```
import re
long_match_set = r"(?: (?:LTD|CORP|LLC|INC))+$"
company_name = "COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD"
clean_company_name = re.sub(long_match_set, "", company_name)
print(clean_company_name)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/C2j5dc)

The regex matches 1 or more groups (`+`) of

- a space and an alternatives group including

  - `LTD` or `CORP` or `LLC` or `INC` before the
- `$` - end of string.

The idea is that we match any `space`+`keyword` that are located in sequence before the end of the string.

Answer (score -2):

Observations:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: %timeit re.compile('( (ltd|corp|llc|inc))+$', re.IGNORECASE).sub('', 'COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.51 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit re.compile('(?: (?:ltd|corp|llc|inc))+$', re.IGNORECASE).sub('', 'COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.48 µs per loop
```

The `?:` is faster but not by much while ignoring case sensitivity.

```
In [4]: %timeit re.compile('(?: (?:ltd|corp|llc|inc))+$').sub('', 'COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.03 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit re.compile('( (ltd|corp|llc|inc))+$').sub('', 'COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.2 µs per loop
```

Ignoring case sensitivity, its much faster.

```
In [6]: %timeit re.compile('( (ltd|corp|llc|inc))+$').sub('', 'COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD wont match')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.61 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit re.compile('(?: (?:ltd|corp|llc|inc))+$').sub('', 'COMPANY_NAME CORP LTD wont match')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.58 µs per loop
```

And on a `NO MATCH` its faster by a little.

I here by suggest you use the `?:`

Comment: @nhahtdh: You guys were right, that was a typo and i ran with it. Ive since corrected my answer